# re/im to polar in java like in labview

Tags: java, trigonometry, labview

I usually programmed on `labview` programming language but now I want to rewrite some functions from `labview` to `java` especially `re/im to polar` and `polar to re/im`. I didn't find any information about this. So how can I write them on java? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so difficult. As you can see here https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/re_im_to_polar/ it is just simple trigonometry functions like `arctan2`, `cos` and `sin`

```java
public float[] ReImToPolar(float x, float y)
    {
        float[] arr = new float[2];
        arr[0] = (float)Math.sqrt((x * x + y * y));  // r
        arr[1] = (float)Math.atan2(y, x);  // theta
        return arr;
    }

public float[] PolarToReIm(float r, float theta)
    {
        float[] arr = new float[2];
        arr[0] = r * (float)Math.cos(theta);  // x
        arr[1] = r * (float)Math.sin(theta);  // y
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why you are using `float` instead of `double`?

Comment: Of course not, it's just part of my code and I need to use ```float``` there. And so of course you can use ```double```